# Python bindings for solc

Tags: solc

There are javascript bindings for solc.  Is there an equivalent Python binding for solc, such that you could simply install solc via pip?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Pyethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/blob/master/.travis.yml) and [Pyethapp](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp/blob/287e36e49736cfd2ec150822010d0c0f4d85c781/.travis.yml) travis.yml files, it would appear not. They both use APT for `solc` (though `pip` for other things).

Answer (score 1):

Now there is a project called py-solc: https://github.com/ethereum/py-solc

Comment: this requires solc to be installed, you should have note of that in your answer

Comment: Please try not to post link-only answers. You should describe why the link provided answers the question and what exactly the link is to.